# Simple Referenced-by Relation in Nodejs Bookshelf

Tags: node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm using the [Bookshelf](http://bookshelfjs.org/) library as an ORM in my server and I'm having trouble defining a very simple relation.

I have an utility table that is being referenced by a lot of other tables without any foreign keys to those tables.

For example:

`Languages` table with records of languages (id, value)

`Posts` table with post data and the post's language(id, ...., language_id)

`Users` table with user data the user's chosen language (id, ..., language_id)

And some other tables with the same logic - just keeping a foreign key to the `Language` table.

According to the documentation, the foreign key parameter on the [belongsTo](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-belongsTo) method should point to a field in the model where it is defined.

**So I've defined my models like this:**

```
var Language = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'languages',
  idAttribute: 'LanguageID',

});

var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'posts',
   idAttribute: 'PostID',

   Language: function() {
       return this.belongsTo(Language, 'LanguageID');
   },
});
```

**My query is:**

```
 Post
   .where({PostID: 1})
   .fetch({withRelated:['Language']})
   .then(function(post) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(post.related('Language')));
    });
```

**The error message is:**

```
Unhandled rejection Error: A valid target model must be defined 
for the posts belongsTo relation
```

I've tried to define almost every other possible relationship between these tables and the `Languages` table but I keep getting error messages about not defining the relation the right way.

How can I achieve this kind of relation?

Comment: found any answer/solution

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your exact error message but probably your code is not matching case somewhere.

Here is a working example using SQLite3 (node 4.2.2, bookshelf 0.9.1, knex 0.9.0 and sqlite3 3.1.1):

With `sqlite3 data.sqlite3`:

```
create table languages (languageid int primary key, name text);
create table posts(postid int primary key, languageid int, text text);
insert into languages values (1, 'english');
insert into languages values (2, 'german');
insert into posts values(1, 2, 'etwas geschrieben');
insert into posts values(2, 1, 'something written');
insert into posts values(3, 1, 'something else written');
```

On node:

```
var knex = require('knex')({client:'sqlite3',connection:{filename: 'data.sqlite3'}});
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
var Language = bookshelf.Model.extend({tableName: 'languages', idAttribute: 'languageid'});
var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({tableName: 'posts', idAttribute: 'postid', Language: function(){return this.belongsTo(Language,'languageid');}});

Post.where({postid: 3}).fetch({withRelated:['Language']}).then(function(p) {console.log(p.toJSON());});
// Outputs:
// { postid: 3,
//   languageid: 1,
//   text: 'something else written',
//   Language: { languageid: 1, name: 'english' } }

Post.where({postid: 3}).fetch({withRelated:['Language']}).then(function(p) {console.log(p.related('Language').toJSON());});
// Outputs: 
// { languageid: 1, name: 'english' }
```

If, instead, I define Post using a wrongly cased `languages` on the `belongsTo()`:

```
var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({tableName: 'posts', idAttribute: 'postid', Language: function(){return this.belongsTo(language,'languageid');}});
// note there was no error yet
Post.where({postid: 3}).fetch({withRelated:['Language']}).then(function(p) {console.log(p.related('Language').toJSON());});
// Fails with: Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: language is not defined
```

Additionally, if you define the relationship key with different case than the one used when defining the target, it will silently not match:

```
// note using `LanguageID` instead of `languageid`
var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({tableName: 'posts', idAttribute: 'PostID', Language: function(){return this.belongsTo(Language,'LanguageID');}});
Post.where({PostID: 3}).fetch({withRelated:['Language']}).then(function(p) {console.log(p.related('Language').toJSON());});
// Outputs and empty list (no matches!):
// {}
```

So I suggest you to review the cases used for the keys and the object names placed on the relationship clauses.